Authenticating to Apache Spark History server with LDAP while deploying on EKS
We are looking for a way to configure LDAP authentication to my Apache Spark Web UI(History server). The Spark instances are running inside a Kubernetes cluster and we have chosen S3 bucket for storing events/logs. Is there a mechanism to authenticate my AD users using LDAP while accessing Spark History server UI.

The simplest method by far would be to put a basic forms authentication page on the front end, then query AD on behalf of the users to either retrieve a full token or (more likely) just check if they are a member of a group... Reasons not to do this are the app is trusted with the credentials... This is not a typical scenario (aka starting from zero authentication or authorization)

Since the Apache Spark History Server doesn't natively support LDAP authentication, one common approach is to deploy an authentication proxy in front of the Spark History Server. This proxy can handle LDAP authentication and forward authenticated requests to the Spark UI. it's the simplest way to do it you can use Nginx with a custom configuration :
http {
    ldap_server ad_server {
        url ldap://your-ad-server.com:389/DC=yourdomain,DC=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=person);
        binddn "CN=bind_user,CN=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com";
        binddn_passwd "your_bind_user_password";
        group_attribute member;
        group_attribute_is_dn on;
        require valid_user;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name spark-history.yourdomain.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificates/your-cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/your-key.key;

        location / {
            auth_ldap "LDAP Authentication";
            auth_ldap_servers ad_server;

            proxy_pass http://spark-history-server-service:18080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}

Another way is the Java Servelet filters as indicated in the official docs here, so you need to create your own filter and enable it with spark.ui.filters
